# fetch value from json using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the below JSON which I am getting after executing certain commands

```
cluster.status()
{
    "clusterName": "ICluster", 
    "defaultReplicaSet": {
        "name": "default", 
        "primary": "?", 
        "ssl": "REQUIRED", 
        "status": "ERROR", 
        "statusText": "Cluster has no quorum as visible from 'X92A1DB:3306' and no ONLINE members that can be used to restore it. 3 members are not active.", 
        "topology": {
            "X92A1DB:3306": {
                "address": "X92A1DB:3306", 
                "instanceErrors": [
                    "ERROR: group_replication has stopped with an error."
                ], 
                "memberRole": "SECONDARY", 
                "mode": "R/O", 
                "readReplicas": {}, 
                "role": "HA", 
                "status": "ERROR", 
                "version": "5.7.36"
            }, 
            "X92A2DB:3306": {
                "address": "X92A2DB:3306", 
                "instanceErrors": [
                    "ERROR: split-brain! Instance is not part of the majority group, but has state ONLINE"
                ], 
                "memberRole": "SECONDARY", 
                "memberState": "ONLINE", 
                "mode": "R/O", 
                "readReplicas": {}, 
                "role": "HA", 
                "status": "(MISSING)", 
                "version": "5.7.36"
            }, 
            "X92A3DB:3306": {
                "address": "X92A3DB:3306", 
                "instanceErrors": [
                    "ERROR: split-brain! Instance is not part of the majority group, but has state ONLINE", 
                    "WARNING: Instance is NOT a PRIMARY but super_read_only option is OFF."
                ], 
                "memberRole": "SECONDARY", 
                "memberState": "ONLINE", 
                "mode": "R/O", 
                "readReplicas": {}, 
                "role": "HA", 
                "status": "(MISSING)", 
                "version": "5.7.36"
            }
        }, 
        "topologyMode": "Single-Primary", 
        "warning": "The cluster description may be inaccurate as it was generated from an instance in Error state"
    }, 
    "groupInformationSourceMember": "X921DB:3306"
}
```

I need to identify the node name **X92A1DB:3306** and having **"status": "ERROR"** or have to get **"ERROR: group_replication has stopped with an error."**

Based on which I need to execute further commands.

Below is the code using which I am getting the above output (**output of Cluster.status()**)

```
$NewServerList=@()
$GetServerData = @(Import-Csv -Path "E:\MySQL_Cluster\NONPRODServerDetails.csv")

foreach($S_List in $GetServerData)
{

$S_1 = $S_List.IP
$session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $S_1 -Credential $Mysqlcred
$Strem = New-SSHShellStream -SSHSession $Session
       
        $cmd_1 = $Strem.WriteLine("sudo su - mysql")
        sleep -Seconds 5
        $Strem.read()
        $cmd_5 = $Strem.WriteLine("var cluster = dba.getCluster('ICluster')")
        sleep -Seconds 5
        $IBCL = $Strem.read()
        Write-Host $IBCL
        $statustowrite = $Strem.WriteLine("cluster.status()")
        sleep -Seconds 5
        "Initial Cluster Status"| Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Force -Append
        "==============================================="|Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Force -Append
        $Strem.Read() | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Force -Append
        "==============================================="| Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Force -Append
    }
```

Please let me know how to get it.

Comment: `ConvertFrom-Json` is your friend here (after skipping the `cluster.status()` line).

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
(Get-Content "path_to_json" | Select-Object -Skip 1) | ConvertFrom-Json
```